# Calculate the geo position at given time

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

With `Google API directions` I can get all the information to go from one place to another and I can get all the steps as well.

But I don't know if there is a way to retrieve/calculate the position(Lat/Lng) after a given time. Assuming, to simplify, my speed is constant is there I way to answer the question: where will I be in X minutes ?

**NOTE**

I know that `Distance travelled = Time * Speed` but in this way I know how many KM I travelled. What I want to know is the (Lat/Lng) after a period of time.

Comment: Time = Distance/Speed if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @Matthew That would work if I'm travelling on a perfect straight road.

Comment: @Hpatoio You said that you were assuming that speed is constant, regardless of the curves on the road you would still get the correct time from that answer because the distance does not become indifferent to a regular number (which can be applied to that formula).

Comment: @Matthew I've update my question. I don't need to know how many KM I've travelled but the Lat/Lng after X minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-timeOnRoute.html) using GetPointAtDistance from the [epoly.js third party library from Mike Williams](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.htm) ported to v3

```
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;
  var polyline = null;

function createMarker(latlng, label, html) {
// alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");
    var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: label,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
        marker.myname = label;
        // gmarkers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    return marker;
}

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers:true});
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: chicago
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    calcRoute();
  }

  function calcRoute() {

    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: travelMode
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        polyline.setPath([]);
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        startLocation = new Object();
        endLocation = new Object();
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var route = response.routes[0];
        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
        summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";

        // For each route, display summary information.
    var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
    var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
        for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
          if (i == 0) { 
            startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
            startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
            // marker = google.maps.Marker({map:map,position: startLocation.latlng});
            marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,"green");
          }
          endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
          endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
          var steps = legs[i].steps;
          for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) {
            var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
            for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) {
              polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
              bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
            }
          }
        }

        polyline.setMap(map);

        computeTotalDistance(response);
      } else {
        alert("directions response "+status);
      }
    });
  }

var totalDist = 0;
var totalTime = 0;
      function computeTotalDistance(result) {
      totalDist = 0;
      totalTime = 0;
      var myroute = result.routes[0];
      for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        totalDist += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
        totalTime += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;      
      }
      totalDist = totalDist / 1000.
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "total distance is: "+ totalDist + " km<br>total time is: " + (totalTime / 60).toFixed(2) + " minutes";
      document.getElementById("totalTime").value = (totalTime/60.).toFixed(2);
      }

      function putMarkerOnRoute(time) {
        var distance = (time*60/totalTime) * totalDist*1000;
        // alert("Time:"+time+" totalTime:"+totalTime+" totalDist:"+totalDist+" dist:"+distance);
    if (!marker) {
          marker = createMarker(polyline.GetPointAtDistance(distance),"time: "+time,"marker");
    } else {
          marker.setPosition(polyline.GetPointAtDistance(distance));
          marker.setTitle("time:"+time);
        }
      }
```

v3_epoly.js

```
/*********************************************************************\
*                                                                     *
* epolys.js                                          by Mike Williams *
* updated to API v3                                  by Larry Ross    *
*                                                                     *
* A Google Maps API Extension                                         *
*                                                                     *
* Adds various Methods to google.maps.Polygon and google.maps.Polyline *
*                                                                     *
* .GetPointAtDistance() returns a GLatLng at the specified distance   *
*                   along the path.                                   *
*                   The distance is specified in metres               *
*                   Reurns null if the path is shorter than that      *
*                                                                     *
* .GetPointsAtDistance() returns an array of GLatLngs at the          *
*                   specified interval along the path.                *
*                   The distance is specified in metres               *
*                                                                     *
***********************************************************************
*                                                                     *
*   This Javascript is provided by Mike Williams                      *
*   Blackpool Community Church Javascript Team                        *
*   http://www.blackpoolchurch.org/                                   *
*   http://econym.org.uk/gmap/                                        *
*                                                                     *
*   This work is licenced under a Creative Commons Licence            *
*   http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/uk/                    *
*                                                                     *
***********************************************************************
*                                                                     *
* Version 1.1       6-Jun-2007                                        *
* Version 1.2       1-Jul-2007 - fix: Bounds was omitting vertex zero *
*                                add: Bearing                         *
* Version 1.3       28-Nov-2008  add: GetPointsAtDistance()           *
* Version 1.4       12-Jan-2009  fix: GetPointsAtDistance()           *
* Version 3.0       11-Aug-2010  update to v3                         *
*                                                                     *
\*********************************************************************/

// === first support methods that don't (yet) exist in v3
google.maps.LatLng.prototype.distanceFrom = function(newLatLng) {
  var EarthRadiusMeters = 6378137.0; // meters
  var lat1 = this.lat();
  var lon1 = this.lng();
  var lat2 = newLatLng.lat();
  var lon2 = newLatLng.lng();
  var dLat = (lat2-lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
  var dLon = (lon2-lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180 ) *
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  var d = EarthRadiusMeters * c;
  return d;
}

google.maps.LatLng.prototype.latRadians = function() {
  return this.lat() * Math.PI/180;
}

google.maps.LatLng.prototype.lngRadians = function() {
  return this.lng() * Math.PI/180;
}

// === A method which returns the length of a path in metres ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Distance = function() {
  var dist = 0;
  for (var i=1; i < this.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i-1));
  }
  return dist;
}

// === A method which returns a GLatLng of a point a given distance along the path ===
// === Returns null if the path is shorter than the specified distance ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointAtDistance = function(metres) {
  // some awkward special cases
  if (metres == 0) return this.getPath().getAt(0);
  if (metres < 0) return null;
  if (this.getPath().getLength() < 2) return null;
  var dist=0;
  var olddist=0;
  for (var i=1; (i < this.getPath().getLength() && dist < metres); i++) {
    olddist = dist;
    dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i-1));
  }
  if (dist < metres) {
    return null;
  }
  var p1= this.getPath().getAt(i-2);
  var p2= this.getPath().getAt(i-1);
  var m = (metres-olddist)/(dist-olddist);
  return new google.maps.LatLng( p1.lat() + (p2.lat()-p1.lat())*m, p1.lng() + (p2.lng()-p1.lng())*m);
}

// === A method which returns an array of GLatLngs of points a given interval along the path ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointsAtDistance = function(metres) {
  var next = metres;
  var points = [];
  // some awkward special cases
  if (metres <= 0) return points;
  var dist=0;
  var olddist=0;
  for (var i=1; (i < this.getPath().getLength()); i++) {
    olddist = dist;
    dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i-1));
    while (dist > next) {
      var p1= this.getPath().getAt(i-1);
      var p2= this.getPath().getAt(i);
      var m = (next-olddist)/(dist-olddist);
      points.push(new google.maps.LatLng( p1.lat() + (p2.lat()-p1.lat())*m, p1.lng() + (p2.lng()-p1.lng())*m));
      next += metres;    
    }
  }
  return points;
}

// === Copy all the above functions to GPolyline ===
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.Distance             = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Distance;
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetPointAtDistance   = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointAtDistance;
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetPointsAtDistance  = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointsAtDistance;
```