# finding waypoints by travel time

Tags: google-maps

I am driving across country and have several stops to make.  Google Maps will plan the route between these stops but some of the drive times are a little excessive.

Is there a way, given a route between two points, to determine where I would be based on the amount of time I want to drive?

I know I can get the drive time between two points, but I want to find a point given a starting location and the number of hours of drive time along my route.

Mark

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [ask]

Comment: [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-timeOnRoute.html) from my answer to the question: [Calculate the geo position at given time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562799/calculate-the-geo-position-at-given-time)